# OpenVPN Server configuration to route internet trafic

Tags: openvpn

I have a problem to configure OpenVPN.

This happens when I am connected:
I can ping the server 192.168.42.1 from the client 192.168.42.6 and vice versa.
I can access to the listening daemons on the server on 192.168.42.1 (http and dns).
I can access to the server with its internet IP but the connection is not routed in the VPN (I made a traceroute, it pass through my home router).
I can't access to any other internet IP (on a nmap traceroute, I just see one line with 192.168.42.1!).

Here is my OpenVPN server configuration:

```
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 192.168.42.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.42.1"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
comp-lzo
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 4
script-security 2
push "redirect-gateway def1"
auth-user-pass-verify /home/openvpn/chroot/login.php via-file
port-share 127.0.0.1 4433
max-clients 10
daemon
```

Here is a part of my iptables configuration:

```
# current configuration (i removed some lines concerning other ports)
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# lines added for OpenVPN
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o em1 -s 192.168.42.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.42.0/24 -o em1 -j MASQUERADE
```

What can I do? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your question and configuration that you intend on allowing internet access to the client through the server.

In that case, it seems to me that your openvpn configuration is correct.

However, your filtering is not complete. As it is, you set it up to forward new packets from tun0 to em0 (which I assume to be the ethernet connection on the server), but not any follow-up packet or any packet at all from em0 to tun0. Bidirectional communication is required for about all internet protocols.

Therefore, I would add in your configuration the lines :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o em1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i em1 -o tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You should also make sur that /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward contains 1, and if not, execute

```
sudo echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Depending on your distribution, there should be a way to make that last setting permanent (the command only make it last until the next reboot).

Comment: I've already activated Ipv4 forwarding. I added these lines, it works for internet except for the IP of my server. Is there a way to route this IP to 192.168.42.1? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are asking. What exactly would be the intended packet flow to your server ?

Comment: As an example, my server has the domain example.com and the internet IP 1.1.1.1. I want to make that 1.1.1.1 is routed to 192.168.42.1. An idea  is to edit my hosts file or to edit my DNS daemon to make this edit. Is there another way?

Comment: Apparently, what I want is not possible, I will change my DNS daemon to edit the records.

Comment: Tweaking your host file or the local dns will make local clients resolve example.com to 192.168.41.1, regardless of the IP 1.1.1.1 (which can still be the ip associated to example.com for the rest of the internet). If your purpose is to force services on the server to be accessed through the VPN for local clients, that seems the most reasonable approach to me. Otherwise, you would need complex routing tables to handle the fact that sometimes the server needs to be accessed through the VPN and sometimes not (the VPN itself needs to use the public ip, otherwise there is a loop)

Comment: I edited my dnsmasq settings to spoof my dns.